# Integer Sides of a right angle

Tags: combinatorics

How many right angled triangles are there, all the sides of which are integers,
having $2009^{12}$ as one of its shorter sides?
Note that a triangle with sides a, b, c is the same as a triangle with sides b, a, c;
where c is the hypotenuse.

I think I got the premise of the solution, but I dont know what I'm not counting

we need

$7^{24}41^{12} =(c-b)(c+b)$

There will always be a c+b for every c-b available, there are $\frac{25*13 + 1}{2} -1$ pairs of factors where$c+b > c-b$
= 163 possibilites. I am far from the answer but I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the formula for generating primitive [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) $(a,b,c)$ we need to find all integers $m,n$ such that
$$
a=2009^{12}=m^2-n^2,\; b=2mn,\; c=m^2+n^2.
$$
So indeed, we need to count all possible different factorizations of $7^{24}41^{12}$ as $(m-n)(m+n)$.

Hint for your question: have a look at [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A046079). So the number is
$$
\frac{(2\cdot 24+1)(2\cdot 12+1)-1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, i really didn't get the sequence that was given, can I just get an intuition about the formula?

Comment: The counting formula for odd $n$ (and $2009^{12}$ is odd) is just $(\tau(n^2)-1)/2$, where $\tau(m)$ is the number of divisors of $m$.